# Nat Deduction Proof - Distributive property

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I need to prove $(P \lor Q) \land (P \lor R) \vdash P \lor (Q \land R)$ using natural deduction and propositional logic.  I should be able to do it using only AND and OR rules, but I am stuck on how to assume $Q$ and $R$.  This is what I have:

$(P \lor Q) \land (P \lor R)$ ________premise

$P \lor Q$ ________________^e1___1

$P \lor R$ ________________^e2___1

...$P$__________________assumption

...$P \lor (Q \land R)$ ___________vi1___4

I know this is right so far.  I just don't know how to introduce my assumptions for $Q$ and $R$.  Do I assume $\neg P$?  If so, which rule is applied, and what is the process, to conclude $Q \land R$?  Thanks for any help you can give me

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\rm \neg P$, then from 2 and 3 derive $\rm Q$ and $\rm R$. From that you have $\rm Q\wedge R$, and so on...

The rule, $\rm \neg P,\, P\vee Q \,\vdash\, Q$ , is called **Deductive Syllogism**.  Sometimes also known as *disjunctive elimination* ($\rm\vee e$), or historically as *modus tollendo ponens*.

Comment: After this you still need excluded middle, which is unnecessary as my proof shows.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which rules you have for eliminating the disjunction.

If you indeed have the Disjunctive Syllogism, you can begin as Graham Kemp writes. But to complete, you will need *Reductio ad Absurdum*. From your question, however, I take it that you should not use that rule, and therefore not the Deductive Syllogism either.

The other standard option is that your disjunction elimination is a case analysis, which allows you to prove directly:

$P \vee Q, P \rightarrow R, Q \rightarrow R \vdash R$

To solve your problem, you need to apply this rule twice. Here is an outline. First, make two more assumptions, namely $Q$ and $R$. Second, introduce conjunction and disjunction to obtain $P \vee (Q \wedge R)$. Apply disjunction elimination for a first time (for example, on $P \vee R$, which will discharge $R$). Then apply it a second time, which will discharge the other assumption.

I can't write down the derivation since I don't know your variant of the calculus. That should be easy for you now, I hope.

Comment: "If you indeed have the Deductive Syllogism, you can begin as Graham Kemp writes. But to complete, you will need Reductio ad Absurdum"

No.  You could have deductive syllogism and the law of the excluded middle (ApNp) as an axiom.  Perhaps the only axiom for the natural deduction system.

Comment: Ok, you probably _can_ replace RAA in some way or other. I think you could replace (at least intuitionist) RAA if you have excluded middle as an axiom **plus** a case analysis rule. - But if you don't have case analysis, but only disjunctive syllogism, how does excluded middle help?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by case analysis exactly.  If you have excluded middle and disjunction elimination, then you can assume A shows it to lead to something, and then assuming $\lnot$A, shows it leads to something, and then conclude that something by disjunction elimination.

Comment: Ah okay. By 'case analysis', I meant exactly the disjunction elimination rule you described. My point was just that in some variants of natural deduction, you don't have that rule, but the disjunctive syllogism instead. And in such variants, you would need RAA (I think).

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to show $\wedge$ distributes over $\vee$ than vice-versa. And the latter follows straightforwardly from the former. So you might first try showing $(Q \vee R) \wedge P \vdash (Q \wedge P) \vee (R \wedge P)$, and use those arguments or the fact itself in the needed proof. To show $\wedge$ distributes over $\vee$, make use of $P \wedge Q \vdash R$ if and only if $P \vdash Q \rightarrow R$. (This shows that $ \_ \wedge Q$ is a left adjoint of $Q \rightarrow \_$, and left adjoints preserve joins. For "and" to distribute over "or" means the same thing as the "and" operator to preserve binary disjunction, a join.) In formal deduction of $(Q \vee R) \wedge P \vdash (Q \wedge P) \vee (R \wedge P)$, you can use the inference law I mentioned to isolate $Q \vee R$ to the left of $\vdash$ and deal with $Q$ and $R$ separately. Even if you want to show the needed result directly, the idea is that whenever you need to show an inference with a hypothesis that is a conjunction where one conjunct is a disjunction, use the inference law I mentioned to create an equivalent inference with hypothesis the disjunction, which inference can be broken up into simpler inferences each involving as hypothesis a disjunct, and each of these inferences can be dealt with by using the reverse direction of the inference law to remove the implication that was created.

Answer (score 0):

Given $( P \lor Q ) \land ( P \lor R )$:

$P \lor Q$. [$\land$ elimination]

$P \lor R$. [$\land$ elimination]

If $P$:

$P \lor ( Q \land R )$. [$\lor$ introduction]

If $Q$:

If $P$:

$P \lor ( Q \land R )$. [$\lor$ introduction]

If $R$:

$Q \land R$. [$\land$ introduction]

$P \lor ( Q \land R )$. [$\lor$ introduction]

$P \lor ( Q \land R )$ [$\lor$ elimination (by $P \lor R$)]

$P \lor ( Q \land R )$ [$\lor$ elimination (by $P \lor Q$)]

Comment: I've provided a full proof because I think it is instructive to see at least once how to express case analysis in a natural deduction proof (Fitch-style) in the natural way.