# Deductive proof - need help, explanation how to

Tags: first-order-logic

I am working on assignment for school where the task asks to give a deductive proof. However, I have never used this technique (nor that I am very good in proofs in general) thus it is quite complicated. Can anyone here give me a short "guide" on how to proof by deduction? (Couldn't find any good guide online). It would be really useful to see how to generate this kind of proofs if anyone could show how to solve this proof:

If $\forall x. (P(x) \to (Q(x) \wedge S(x)))$ and $\forall x. (P(x) \wedge R(x))$, then $\forall x. (R(x) \wedge S(x))$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally you need to show what you've tried, to get good reception on your homework question.

Comment: It's better to ask this question on math.se. Somebody will write a textbook for you.

Comment: Do you know [Natural Deduction](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/) ?

Comment: Sadly, no. This course popped out of nowhere and escalated too quickly.

Comment: Thus, you will **never** get an answer unless you will not "specify" what rules/axioms to be used in a "proof by deduction" you are allowed to use.

Comment: Intuitively, the argument is quite simple: if all "objects" that are $P$s are also ($Q$ and $S$)s, by first premise, and all "objects" are  ($P$ and $R$)s, by second premise, then necessarily all "objects" are  ($P$ and $Q$ and $R$ and $S$)s and thus *a fortiori* they are ($R$ and $S$)s.

Comment: I understand that more information about it would help out, but that's the only thing we got for the task description also. That is mainly why it is so difficult to actually solve it.

Comment: I am not really sure, but I suppose we are allowed to use all inference rules. Does that make any sense?

Comment: No it does not make sense to say we allow the use of **all** valid inference rules, because then any tautology can be proven in one step since it is a valid inference rule! In natural deduction, there are very few rules, but it can prove every tautology. Do you understand my answer?

Answer (score 3):

There are many styles of natural deduction, and the one most suited for practical use is [Fitch-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitch_notation), which uses indentation just like programming languages to denote scoping. Basically, you ensure that every sentence you write is true in its context, where the context is captured by headers exactly as in a multi-level list. We can even throw away the lines at the side. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1474371/21820) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1723026/21820) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1653082/21820) for some examples.

Here is what such a proof of your example will look like:
$\def\imp{\rightarrow}$

> If $\forall x \ ( P(x) \imp Q(x) \land S(x) ) \land \forall x \ ( P(x) \land R(x) )$:
>
> $\forall x \ ( P(x) \imp Q(x) \land S(x) )$.
>
> $\forall x \ ( P(x) \land R(x) )$.
>
> Given any $x$:
>
> $P(x) \imp Q(x) \land S(x)$.
>
> $P(x) \land R(x)$.
>
> $P(x)$.
>
> $R(x)$.
>
> $Q(x) \land S(x)$.
>
> $S(x)$.
>
> $R(x) \land S(x)$.
>
> $\forall x \ ( R(x) \land S(x) )$.
>
> $\forall x \ ( P(x) \imp Q(x) \land S(x) ) \land \forall x \ ( P(x) \land R(x) ) \imp \forall x \ ( R(x) \land S(x) )$.

I'm confident you can figure out how each line follows from the preceding ones. That ultimately is the goal of natural deduction, to make the logical reasoning clear.

Comment: Of course, this may not be what your assignment is looking for but it's usually more instructive to understand proofs in natural deduction than in any other system. The worst is Hilbert systems, which are good for theoretical study of first-order logic systems but quite useless for practical usage.

Answer (score 0):

A proof in natural deduction style is done with things called proof-trees. I don't know how to draw them on SE, so I'll use the other alternative known as Hilbert-style proof.

```
1. ∀ x . P x ⇒ Q x ∧ S x     premise
2. ∀ x . P x ∧ R x            premise
3. ∀ x . R x ∧ S x            goal
   3.1 P x ⇒ Q x ∧ S x       using (1) on x
   3.2 P x ∧ R x              using (2) on x
   3.3 P x                    ∧-elimination1 on 3.2
   3.4 R x                    ∧-elimination2 on 3.2
   3.5 Q x ∧ S x              modus-ponens using 3.1 and 3.3
   3.6 S x                    ∧-elimination2 on 3.5
   3.6 R x ∧ S x              ∧-introduction using 3.4 and 3.6
```

Natural deduction is treated in the early chapters of [this nifty book called: Using Z](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15819/zedbook.pdf). Best of luck!

Comment: PS: This is known as a Fitch style proof.